# My background color for my div is not working

Tags: html, css, background-color

I want to make my element have background #22223b, but my code is not working.

```css
.nav {
  background-color: #22223b;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">About Us</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Start Learning</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="account">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#">Profile</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Portal</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Based on what you wrote this should work ;)

Comment: I see the background for `.nav`. What is not working? Is this CSS in same file else if external file,  did you include it in ur page?

Comment: Always add the minimum amount of code required so we can reproduce your issue **in the question itself**, not on an external page. The code you show here works as intended, no issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background-color should be visible, if it´s not then there is probably some problem with linking the css file.

I added the styling in a `<style>` so the styling applies without needing the css file.

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">About Us</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Start Learning</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="account">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#">Profile</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Portal</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<style>
  .nav {
    background-color: #22223b;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I did that, but it's not working? Do you think I could add you to my repl?

Comment: Sure! I can have a quick look!

Comment: Done! When the elements have float: left the parent div (.nav) gets no height, which means that the background-color cant be shown. https://replit.com/@TahaParacha1/Summit#style.css

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much :D